# Operator displays error in JSHint - Learning syntax if statement

Tags: jquery, syntax

I'm trying to write an if function to check if a slide has the class portrait and if so add the class `portrait_slide` to the parent.

Heres what I have so far *with edit*

```
    $('.cycle-slideshow').on('cycle-next', function (event, opts) {

    var $this = this;

    $('.slide').each(function (index) {
        if this.hasClass('portrait')) {
            this.parent().addClass('portrait_slide');
        }

    });
});
```

But I keep getting an error on the `if this.hasClass('portrait');` line "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if` statements require parenthesis around them.

```
if (this.hasClass('portrait')) { //no semi colon either
```

You also need to understand the difference between `this` and `$(this)`. One is a DOM element, the other is a jQuery object.

I see that you do `$this = this` which is odd, prepending a variable with a `$` typically is a convention for caching a jQuery object. You may want to use `$this = $(this)`, and add the dollar sign before your instances of `this` as needed

`parent()` is a jQuery function, but `this` is the index of a `.slide` element. Either use

```
$(this).parent().addClass();
```

Or use

```
this.parentNode.className += " portrait_slide";
```

The same thing goes for `this.hasClass()`, you're using a jQuery method on a DOM element.

Use either `$(this).hasClass()` or if you use javascript (after googling js class contains)

```
function hasClass( elem, klass ) {
    return (" " + elem.className + " " ).indexOf( " "+klass+" " ) > -1;
}
```

Comment: JShint now tells me that line is missing a semicolon. Is this correct?

Comment: No, please google basic javascript logic. If statements are very basic

Comment: Thank you so much for the extra documentation. Really helps

Answer (score 0):

No semicolon at the end of the if test and needs parentheses around it

Change

```
if this.hasClass('portrait'); {

}
```

To:

```
if(this.hasClass('portrait')) {

}
```